# Where is pure outside static air pressure indication on A320?

Tags: avionics, airbus-a320, pitot-static

I'm looking for the indication of the outside static air pressure in the cockpit.
Where is it located? One of the ECAM pages?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your reason to believe it *should* be displayed as anything else than pressure altitude?

Comment: My incompetence in avionic... Is the static pressure used somewhere else as in pressure altitude? For some other calculations that are not displayed?

Comment: Airspeed measurement requires static pressure (dynamic pressure is total pressure, in pitot probe, minus static pressure), but the usual approach is to measure the difference directly (though I don't know whether A320 ADIRU does that). And then there are some altitude-dependent limits in the flight laws. Also the transponder transmits pressure, ignoring the baro setting.

Comment: Maybe one of the computers with displays shows for maintenance purposes raw static pressure value? So the technician can check pressure against some value in the ground test equipment?

Comment: I doubt practical test equipment would show anything else than pressure altitude to be directly compared with the altimeter. That way it can be used with any altimeter and the point of the test is to check the altimeter reading anyway.